# Trouble with Flask / Jinja2 conditional statement - displaying sqlalchemy class

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I've added a user profile page to my flask app. Everything is working except for one item:

I would like to display is the user's "Account created on" date. As I've added this functionality (and the logic to record a user's creation date upon registering) after some users have already been created, this column in certain user's tables will be empty.

I decided to work around this with a little humor by using a jinja2 if / else statement to check if the user has a user_created date or not.

If the user has a date, it will be displayed. If not, instead of a date it will replace it with 'since the dawn of time'.

The problem is my {% if user.user_created %} conditional logic seems to be pulling the sqlalchemy DateTime class type instead of None displaying as so:

```
Member since: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.DateTime'>
```

If used this same pattern to check for the existence of other data without problems so I'm guessing it's related to this column containing db.Column(db.DateTime), but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Here is my Jinja template code:

```
<h1>User: {{ user.username }}</h1>
  {% if user.about_me %}<p>{{ user.about_me }}</p>{% endif %}
  {% if user.user_created %}
    <p>Member since: {{ user.user_created }}</p>
  {% else %}
    <p>Member since: The dawn of time</p>
  {% endif %}
```

And here is the column from my sqlalchemy User model:

```
user_created = (db.DateTime)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Aw man, after reading this over I just caught that I'm missing the db.Column - I'll make that fix and see if that's the problem (probably is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, after testing the realization in the comment above, that was in fact the issue.

I accidentally omitted the db.Column in my model. All is working now.